For which values of the parameter $S$ is the integral convergent?
I feel like I should take lower limit and I did but I couldn't proceed. I need help. Should I use some comparison test 1
$$\int \limits^{2}_{1} \frac{(1- \cos \pi x)(x-1)^S}{x^3 -1} dx$$

As $x\to1$, $$\frac{(1- \cos \pi x)(x-1)^S}{x^3 -1}\sim\frac23(x-1)^{S-1}.$$

@AnneBauval Thank you for your response but how do I get the value of S?

For which values of $S$ is $(x-1)^{S-1}$ integrable "at $1^+$"? (i.e. on $(1,a)$ for $a>1$) Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions. This is a PSQ.
